# java serialization algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, serialization

I have tried to google around to find some good documentation on the java serialization algorithm, does anyone know where I can find this information in more details?

Thanks ;)

Reason I ask is because I would like to try to make an deserializer in php from a serialized binary javaobject.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html ?

Comment: I would read the source as well.

Comment: Well, that document answers some of the questions ;) but I guess I need to check the sourcecode too. When can I get the sourcecode?

Comment: What questions *aren't* answered by the specification?

Comment: @EJP Oh, there are plenty of questions not answered by the source code. (Riemann conjecture: true or false? RTFA.) Source code is in src.zip of your JDK (or you can load a pre-release OpenJDK 7 from java.net or use Mercurial to get a current version).

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Such as? That's not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the algorithm itself, look at the Java source code.

The Java serialization protocol (format), the APIs and the behavioural specification are all available from the [Java Object Serialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/serialization/index.html) technical guide.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible to parse a Java serialised stream outside of a JRE. Some classes are a bit naughty and miss out calling `defaultWriteObject` in their custom `writeObject` method, which makes the stream unparseable. The data after `defautlWriteObject` is custom, so isn't really parseable without knowing specific details of the class involved anyway. Probably your best route is to start a JRE (or not store the data with Java serialisation in the first palce).

Answer (score 0):

You have to See Object Serialization Stream Protocol,and Understand the following [Concept](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nJrbbmySI70),

```
Stream Elements
Stream Protocol Versions
Grammar for the Stream Format
Rules of the Grammar
```

Before that you have to you have to Understand the TLV(Type Length Value encoding) How to read the hexadecimal value's